# Measure space and inclusion of $L^p$-spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a question about the following reasoning:

Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space
and assume that $\mu(X)$ is finite.

Then by Holder, we know that there exists a constant $C_{p,q}$
such that $$||f||_p \leq C_{p,q} ||f||_q$$, when $p<q$.

Now, consider the identity map $i\colon L^p(\mu)\rightarrow L^q(\mu)$,
Let $(f_i,f_i)\in Graph(i)$, be a sequence in the product space converging to $(f,g)$, which means that $f_i$ converge to $f$ in $L^p$
and $f_i$ converge to $g$ in $L^q$. Then we have that $||f_i-g||_p \leq C_{p,q} ||f_i-g||_q$, which means that $f_i$ converge to $g$ in $L^p$, then $f=g$ almost everywhere. Since the identity map is continuous (by closed Graph Theorem)
we conclude that there exists a constant $C'_{p,q}$ such that
$||f||_q \leq C'_{p,q}||f||_p$. Thus, the space $X$ does not contain elements of arbitrarily small measure... But that is not true in general.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:** $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$. The function $f(x):=x^{-2/5}$ is in $L^2$ but not in $L^3$. You err in assuming that the identity maps $L^2$ into $L^3$ (for example).

Answer (score 0):

The identity mapping $i : L^p(\mu) \to L^q(\mu)$ is not always defined.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being a parrot, as the other answers point out, you have to be careful about embeddings. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Embeddings) is a very brief explanation of what you're after I believe. (Notice in particular the second biconditional...)